# Как правильно составить LEFT JOIN SQL запрос?

Tags: sql

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы в `LEFT JOIN Nacenki` при `Nacenki.IdPriznPartn = NULL`, `LEFT JOIN` отрабатывал с `1`? Сейчас, когда такого `IdPriznPartn` в таблице не существует, мне возвращается `Nacenki.NacRozn = NULL`, а мне нужно чтобы возвращалось значение при `Nacenki.IdPriznPartn = 1` (только когда `Nacenki.IdPriznPartn = NULL`, а `1` потому что этот признак в таблице всегда существует).

Если короче, Nacenki.NacRozn AS INCRATE, не должно быть NULL (если такого Nacenki.IdPriznPartn не существует - я хочу чтобы это отработало с Nacenki.IdPriznPartn = 1)...

```
= CASE WHEN Nacenki.IdPriznPart IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE Nacenki.IdPriznPart END 
= 1
----Не сработало, `Nacenki.NacRozn` всё равно получал `NULL`

SELECT     
    DocStrOst.PNT AS ID,
    SprTovar.NameT AS NAME,
    SprEdiz.Ediz AS UNIT,
    tbPredpr.namePredpr AS POST,
    SprTovar.MinUp AS KOL1M,
    DocStrOst.KolF AS STOCK,
    SprTovar.CenO AS PRICE,
    SprTovar.NDS AS NDS,
    Nacenki.NacRozn AS INCRATE,
    SprTovar.SkidPost AS DISCRATE,
    SprTovar.KodGr AS IDGR1,
    SprTovar.KodPGr AS IDGR2,
    SprGrup.NameGr AS GR1,
    SprPGrup.NamePGr AS GR2
FROM
    DocStrOst 
INNER JOIN
    SprTovar ON DocStrOst.PNT = SprTovar.PNT
INNER JOIN
    SprEdiz ON SprTovar.EdIzID = SprEdiz.EdizId
LEFT JOIN
    tbPredpr ON SprTovar.IdPost = tbPredpr.idPredpr
LEFT JOIN
    Nacenki ON SprTovar.IdPriznNac = Nacenki.IdPriznNac AND
    SprTovar.KodGr = Nacenki.KodGr AND
    SprTovar.KodPGr = Nacenki.KodPGr AND
    CASE WHEN tbPredpr.IdPriznPartn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE tbPredpr.IdPriznPartn END
    =
    Nacenki.IdPriznPartn
INNER JOIN
    SprGrup ON SprTovar.KodGr = SprGrup.KodGr--
INNER JOIN
    SprPGrup ON SprTovar.KodGr = SprPGrup.KodGr AND SprTovar.KodPGr = SprPGrup.KodPGr
WHERE 
    DocStrOst.KodSkl = 325 AND
    DocStrOst.KolF > 0
ORDER BY
    SprTovar.NameT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN tbPredpr.IdPriznPartn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE
        CASE
            WHEN 
                (SELECT
                    COUNT(Nacenki.IdPriznPartn)
                FROM
                    Nacenki
                WHERE
                    Nacenki.IdPriznNac = SprTovar.IdPriznNac AND
                    Nacenki.KodGr = SprTovar.KodGr AND
                    Nacenki.KodPGr = SprTovar.KodPGr AND
                    Nacenki.IdPriznPartn  = tbPredpr.IdPriznPartn)
            = 0
            THEN
                1
            ELSE
                tbPredpr.IdPriznPartn
            END
    END
    =
    Nacenki.IdPriznPartn
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать из JOIN'а условие CASE WHEN. Вместо этого используйте:

```
SELECT ... IFNULL(tbPredpr.IdPriznPartn, 1) ...
```

Функция IFNULL возвращает значение IdPriznPartn, если оно не NULL, иначе - 1.

Актуально для MySQL. http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Control_flow_functions.html

Comment: В любом случае, лучше убрать условие из секции ON объединения. И использовать IF в SELECT.

Comment: Спасибо, вы подтолкнули меня на правильное решение!

Comment: Вместо IFNULL так же можно использовать функцию coalesce(), она входит в стандарты и поддерживается подавляющим большинством sql диалектов.